# Vertical navigation scroll effect modification

Tags: javascript

I got this pen: https://codepen.io/janmez/pen/gryoKG but would like it to work more like on this site: https://rallyinteractive.com/. Not the background change, just list on the left. My js knowledge is not sufficient, can you help?

I tried achieving this with css but no success.

Edit: I added the full code and now what I want to achieve. I don't care about background animation, just wanted to make the nav and .content-section work more like on the site I mentioned above. Pen code does some of what I want: nav items get selected while scrolling to the relevant section. What I want to do is to have active nav elements always centered vertically and scroll together with sections. The example site (rallyinteractive.com) does exactly what I need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contentSection = $('.content-section');
    var navigation = $('nav');
    
    //when a nav link is clicked, smooth scroll to the section
    navigation.on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevents previous event
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });
    
    //update navigation on scroll...
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        updateNavigation();
    })
    //...and when the page starts
    updateNavigation();
    
    /////FUNCTIONS
    function updateNavigation(){
        contentSection.each(function(){
            var sectionName = $(this).attr('id');
            var navigationMatch = $('nav a[href="#' + sectionName + '"]');
            if( ($(this).offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < $(window).scrollTop()) &&
                  ($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() - $(window).height()/2 > $(window).scrollTop()))
                {
                    navigationMatch.addClass('active-section');
                }
            else {
                navigationMatch.removeClass('active-section');
            }
        });
    }
    function smoothScroll(target){
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
    }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

html{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #E9E8E2;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}
nav{
    width: 15%;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 10;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
text-align:center;
    valign:center;
}
li{
    padding: 40px 0;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #272727;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.circle{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #272727;
}
.rect{
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #272727;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, width 1s;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, width 1s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, width 1s;
}
nav a:hover, nav .active-section{
    color: #9b59b6;
}
nav a:hover span, nav .active-section span{
    background-color: #9b59b6;
}
nav .active-section .rect{
    width: 40px;
}
.content-section{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #ecf1f1;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.content-section h1{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    color:#9b59b6;
    font-size: 3em;
}

/*CREDITS*/
.about{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0; 
    left: 1%;
}
.about a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.about a:visited, .about a:active, .about a:link{
    color:#000;
}
.about a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#section1">
                <span class="rect"></span>
                <span class="circle"></span>
                ONE
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section2">
                <span class="rect"></span>
                <span class="circle"></span>
                TWO
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section3">
                <span class="rect"></span>
                <span class="circle"></span>
                THREE
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section4">
                <span class="rect"></span>
                <span class="circle"></span>
                FOUR
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section5">
                <span class="rect"></span>
                <span class="circle"></span>
                FIVE
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="section1" class="content-section">
    <h1>SECTION ONE</h1>
</section>
<section id="section2" class="content-section">
    <h1>SECTION TWO</h1>
</section>
<section id="section3" class="content-section">
    <h1>SECTION THREE</h1>
</section>
<section id="section4" class="content-section">
    <h1>SECTION FOUR</h1>
</section>
<section id="section5" class="content-section">
    <h1>SECTION FIVE</h1>
</section>
    <div class="about"><a href="http://janetmndz.com" target="_blank">♡</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS and HTML as well. Regarding the background and not wanting it to change (I assume you mean scroll, if not, please explain in greater detail) - have you looked into [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment), [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), and [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) rules (to name a few)?

Comment: Ok, here's my pen: <https://codepen.io/kinga-szumilas/pen/QWBveZB> - this is almost what I need. I need to make the two corresponding active elements to display side by side and be centered vertically. Now the content changes but stays at the top. I want everything displayed beautifully in line, numbers scroll down and the content just change.